# <use> tag in an <apex:repeat /> preventing reRender of apex:repeat

Tags: lightning-design-system, rerender, slds

I'm creating a VF page using the Salesforce Lightning Design System, as part of this, I want to use [SLDS Notifications](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/notifications/) to display page messages and other notifications.

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="repeatPanel" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!customPageMessages}" var="m" id="repeat">
        <div class="slds-notify_container slds-m-vertical--x-small">
          <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--alert-texture slds-theme--{!m.severity}" role="alert">
            <button class="slds-button slds-notify__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onClick="dismiss(this)">
              <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
              </svg>
              <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">{!m.severity}</span>
            <h2>{!m.message}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

I have run into an issue with not being able to reRender my `<apex:repeat>` tag.   Looking at the logs it does appear that VF is evaluating my merge fields and formulas. After some investigating I've narrowed it down to this line.

`<use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>`

If I remove the `<use>` tag everything renders the way I'd expect it.  However with the `<use>` tag in the markup, nothing gets rendered.

This happens in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: I think this is known limitation of the browser .Since the SVG use xlink you can't reRender SVG component.

Comment: My bad - didn't notice the `apex` tags - have deleted my answer.

Comment: There is a solution, I think - look at the end of this thread: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000BWYqIAO

Comment: Also check this: https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/47 (hard to work out which solutions worked, but it seems some did)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Rohit Mourya

I think this is known limitation of the browser .Since the SVG use xlink you can't reRender SVG component.

Comment: You can rerender the component if the parent element has the xmnls values https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164801/visualforce-page-actionfunction-rerender-not-working/165279#165279