# Loss of Lightning Card style on reRender of outputPanel in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, rerender, slds, outputpanel

I have a visualforce page that gets initially loaded, then an action function is triggered that does a webservice callout.  Once the action is finished and the output panel rerenders, I am losing the styles from the SLDS.

Here, I have an overlay running while the spinner is running, but you can tell that the styles are applied.  IE, you can see the box around it.

[image]

But here, after the outputPanel gets re-renedered after my action function has rerendered, it looks like this:

[image]

Tested this using the generic card example from SLDS, but removed the SVG, as I do not need it, and it seemed to have caused problems in the past based on my searching.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="FlexAccountPanel">
    <article class="slds-card">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">

                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="[object Object]">
                            <span class="slds-text-heading_small">Card Header</span>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="slds-no-flex">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">Card Body (custom goes in here)</div>
        <footer class="slds-card__footer">Card Footer</footer>
    </article>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

And my actionFunction in case you want to see it

```
<apex:actionFunction name="getClaimData" action="{!getFlexInfo}" rerender="FlexAccountPanel, FlexClaimPanel" status="sts" oncomplete="resetTableSort();">
        <apex:param name="CustomerNo" value="" assignTo="{!CustomerNo}"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

It may be important to note that I do not lose my table styles when my other panel gets rerended using the SLDS, I just seem to lose the card styling, mostly the container it would seem.

Comment: I suggest you use your browser's "Inspect" feature to examine the HTML~ before and after the re-render to confirm that the HTML/CSS is the same. If it is the same, try a browser that has a different rendering engine e.g. Firefox if you are using Chrome and vice versa to try ti see if it is a browser rendering bug.

Comment: @KeithC  I ended up changing the `<article` to `<div` and it seemed to work better for what I needed.  Which was basically the box.  Once I had the box back with the div, the gray background came back.  I don't know why the article tag didn't work.

Comment: Weird. Glad you found a wohrk around.

Comment: check out my answer here (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/306494/25289)